# Packing generic types in C#

Tags: c#, casting, binary

I am trying to write a bit packer in c#, and instead of overloading the pack function for every single primitive type I am trying to use dynamic variable to handle a wider range of values. Currently I am only expecting the variable types found in the GetSizeOf function to be passed in and will throw an exception if anything else is passed. But I'm having trouble casting  value into a ulong. I have tried it with an int32, byte and int. also, data is a string which when finished packing should contain the binary sequence of the packed data, including the excess 0's.

If there is a better way to do this, please let me know.

```
    public static int GetSizeOf<V>(V v)
    {
        if (v is Byte) { return sizeof(Byte) * 8; };
        if (v is SByte) { return sizeof(SByte) * 8; };
        if (v is Int16) { return sizeof(Int16) * 8; };
        if (v is UInt16) { return sizeof(UInt16) * 8; };
        if (v is Int32) { return sizeof(Int32) * 8; };
        if (v is UInt32) { return sizeof(UInt32) * 8; };
        if (v is Int64) { return sizeof(Int64) * 8; };
        if (v is UInt64) { return sizeof(UInt64) * 8; };
        throw new Exception("Unable to determine size of " + typeof(V));
    }

    public void pack<T>(T value)
    {
        if (!(value as ulong?).HasValue)
            throw new Exception("Unable to cast " + typeof(T) + " as ulong");
        ulong num = (value as ulong?).Value;
        int size = GetSizeOf(value);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            data = (num & 1) + data;
            num >>= 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are not using dynamic, you are using generics. There is a difference...generics do not allow what you have written, even though you do your own type checking...

Comment: As above, you are not using dynamics, you are using generics.  The two are useful for very different things and the confusion leads me to wonder what you are using this bit packer for, so we might figure out which approach is more appropriate?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I'm somewhat new to the usage of generics and dynamics, and I have been playing with both so much over the weekend that my I got a little confused. I'm planing on using the packer to pack several variables into a binary stream that I can then send out via a udp client. Using it to send small amounts of data for a multiplayer card game (Sheepshead).

Comment: To be honest the generics seem a little pointless here too - the only benefit you get from them is strong typing when calling GetSizeOf and Pack - yet you would need to specify the type when calling these methods anyway...it kind of defeats the point of a generic to type check the hell out of it...might as well just use 'object'

Comment: Looks like all the types you are interested in implement `IConvertible`

Comment: Also, I should note that I am trying to make this modular enough that it can be used for other applications aside from just the Sheepshead game which is why I am not simply hard-coding the packer.

Comment: Could just use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx

Comment: That is almost exactly what I wanted to write. I'm not sure how I didn't find it, but thank you very much for showing it to me. Though I am still curious as to why I can't do "value as ulong?"

Comment: @Lexxicon It is to protect the dev from himself. I believe (but am not 100% sure) that if you added a constraint to force the type to be a ref type, then you could use `as`. But, what if the type was a value type, then `as` will not work...so the compiler doesnt care that you check the feasibility or not...do a search on Unbounded Types with respect to generics and you will get a little more info.

Comment: Thank you Justin. I've been teaching c# to myself for the last couple years after being taught C and C++ for five years or so from high school through college and I am still frustrated by the concept of protecting the dev from himself and I still tend to overlook that as a reason for something not working. So thank you for giving me a direction to look. Also, first time actually asking on stack overflow, is there a way to mark a comment as being the solution or something?